# uninstallation of an application doesn't remove files in ~

Tags: wine, uninstall

I uninstall wine 1.6.1 from software center, because I will install a higher version of wine by compiling from source.

But the uninstallation doesn't remove those files in ~.

```
~/.wine/drive_c$ ls *
os433025.bin

Program Files:
Common Files                            Internet Explorer  Microsoft Visual Studio    NewSoft           Ultrapico
Djvu Bookmarker                         JGsoft             Microsoft Visual Studio 8  OpenBUGS
Foxit Software                          MathType           Microsoft Works            Tracker Software
InstallShield Installation Information  Microsoft.NET      MSBuild                    TTKN

users:
Public  tim

windows:
assembly      Fonts   Installer      notepad.exe  SHELLNEW    temp           Vbox          win.ini~
COCR2.INI     help    logs           PCHEALTH     system      twain_32.dll   winhelp.exe   winsxs
command       hh.exe  Microsoft.NET  regedit.exe  system32    twain.dll      winhlp32.exe  xinstaller.dll
explorer.exe  inf     mono           rundll.exe   system.ini  UnDeployV.exe  win.ini       xinstaller.exe
```

Why are they not removed?
Are there some reasons why they are still worth keeping?

If I want to remove all the files of an application, that are not used by other applications, which command shall I use?

Answer (score 0):

The "purge" option to `apt-get` should remove the package and associated configuration file(s)...

`sudo apt-get purge <package_name>`

The apt-get man page (http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) says,

```
purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and
purged (any configuration files are deleted too).
```

Comment: apt-get purge doesn't remove ~/.wine